# Negative Lookahead how use

Tags: regex, regex-negation

the texts:

> 1a2c3

i want all number which does not have `a` berfore it: 1, 3

I thought it was a classic case of negative lookahead:

> (?!a)[1-9]

but the [result](https://regex101.com/r/N0HwWZ/1) is: 1,2,3

What is my mistake? And what way do I need to find only those who have no match whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look-behind: `?<!`

```
/(?<!a)[1-9]/
```

https://regex101.com/r/E7k5t4/1